# Take values in a pandas multiindex and make them into a list and into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex that results from using `.extractall()`:

```
                       0       1    2        3    4   5    6    7    8   \
      match
0     0           Leather     NaN  NaN  Leather  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1     0           Leather     NaN  NaN  Leather  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2     0           Leather     NaN  NaN  Leather  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     0           Leather     NaN  NaN  Leather  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5     0           Leather     NaN  NaN  Leather  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6     0           Leather     NaN  NaN  Leather  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7     0            Canvas  Canvas  NaN      NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8     0            Canvas  Canvas  NaN      NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9     0            Canvas  Canvas  NaN      NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
10    0            Canvas  Canvas  NaN      NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11    0           Leather     NaN  NaN  Leather  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
12    0            Canvas  Canvas  NaN      NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
      1      Calf Leather     NaN  NaN      NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
15    0           Leather     NaN  NaN  Leather  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
16    0           Leather     NaN  NaN  Leather  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
17    0           Leather     NaN  NaN  Leather  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
18    0           Leather     NaN  NaN  Leather  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
20    0           Leather     NaN  NaN  Leather  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

If you look at index 12, it shows that this entry had two matches, "Canvas" and "Calf Leather". How can I transfrom this multiindex into a column that shows all of the matched attributes? I would like to know how to do this in two ways. Here is the first result I would like:

```
                  material      

0                Leather     
1                Leather     
2                Leather     
3                Leather
4                  Nan      
5                Leather     
6                Leather     
7                 Canvas  
8                 Canvas  
9                 Canvas  
10                Canvas  
11               Leather  
12   Canvas, Calf Leather  
13                 NaN
14                 Nan 
15               Leather  
16               Leather  
17               Leather  
18               Leather
19                 Nan   
20               Leather
```

It takes all the results for each level of the multiindex and turns them into a list. You will notice that I am only paying attention to column 0 in the original multiindex, which is where all the results from `.extractall` get aggregated. Here is the second result I would like to create:

```
                 material     material1 

0                Leather     NaN
1                Leather     NaN
2                Leather     NaN
3                Leather     NaN
4                   NaN      NaN
5                Leather     NaN
6                Leather     NaN
7                 Canvas     NaN
8                 Canvas     NaN
9                 Canvas     NaN
10                Canvas     NaN
11               Leather     NaN
12                Canvas  Calf Leather
13                   NaN     NaN
14                   NaN     NaN
15               Leather     NaN
16               Leather     NaN
17               Leather     NaN
18               Leather     NaN
19                   NaN     NaN
20               Leather     NaN
```

For the second result, there would be as many additional columns as the largest number of matches in the `.extractall` multiindex.

I am happy to clarify anything that is unclear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for remove columns with all `NaN`s and then `groupby` with aggregate `join`:

```
df1 = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all').groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna()))
#replace to None empty spaces
df1 = df1.replace({'': None})
print (df1)
                       0       1        3

0                Leather    None  Leather
1                Leather    None  Leather
2                Leather    None  Leather
3                Leather    None  Leather
5                Leather    None  Leather
6                Leather    None  Leather
7                 Canvas  Canvas     None
8                 Canvas  Canvas     None
9                 Canvas  Canvas     None
10                Canvas  Canvas     None
11               Leather    None  Leather
12  Canvas, Calf Leather  Canvas     None
15               Leather    None  Leather
16               Leather    None  Leather
17               Leather    None  Leather
18               Leather    None  Leather
20               Leather    None  Leather
```

For same columns length use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and then remove `MultiIndex` in columns by `list comprehension`:

```
df2 = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all').unstack()
df2.columns = ['mat{}_{}'.format(x[0], x[1]) for x in df2.columns]
print (df2)
     mat0_0        mat0_1  mat1_0 mat1_1   mat3_0 mat3_1

0   Leather          None     NaN   None  Leather   None
1   Leather          None     NaN   None  Leather   None
2   Leather          None     NaN   None  Leather   None
3   Leather          None     NaN   None  Leather   None
5   Leather          None     NaN   None  Leather   None
6   Leather          None     NaN   None  Leather   None
7    Canvas          None  Canvas   None      NaN   None
8    Canvas          None  Canvas   None      NaN   None
9    Canvas          None  Canvas   None      NaN   None
10   Canvas          None  Canvas   None      NaN   None
11  Leather          None     NaN   None  Leather   None
12   Canvas  Calf Leather  Canvas    NaN      NaN    NaN
15  Leather          None     NaN   None  Leather   None
16  Leather          None     NaN   None  Leather   None
17  Leather          None     NaN   None  Leather   None
18  Leather          None     NaN   None  Leather   None
20  Leather          None     NaN   None  Leather   None
```

Comment: Looks really good! The only thing missing is filling in rows where there were no results. So in your two above solutions, rows 4, 13, 19, and all others like them should have "None" as their value in column 0 and mat0_1 resepctively.

Comment: I think you need add reindex by range like `df1 = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all').groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna())).reindex(range(len(df.index)))`